# Точное соответствие pattern в string

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть `pattern="МАШИНА"`. Строка, в которой нужно искать равна, например, `"ВОРОНА, МАШИНАН, МАШИНА"`, либо `"МАШИНАН, МАШИНА"`. Может быть и 3 разных слова, но `pattern` остается тем же. Алгоритм идет по таким строкам построчно, то есть проверяет, есть ли `МАШИНА` в строке `"ВОРОНА, МАШИНАН"`, далее в строке `"ЗАЯЦ, МАШИНАН"` и валится на том, что берет первую строку, хотя должен вторую по точному соответствию.

Мне нужно проверить, входит ли в точности `pattern` в `string`. Оператор `in` не работает, поскольку он проверяет посимвольно и вернет не ту строку. Мне нужно именно точное соответствие. Пробовал через `re.search(pattern=f"\s^{name}$\s", string=string)`, но в регулярных выражениях не силен, а времени в данный момент разбираться нет. Как написать правильное регулярное выражение / Или есть решение, которое работает быстрее

Минимально воспроизводимый пример

```
import re


def main():
    strings = [
        "300С",
        "300СА",
        "350СБ, 200А",
        "300Б, 200БД",
        "300Б, 200Б"
    ]

    pattern = "200Б"

    # Выведет первую строку, но мне нужна вторая, то есть 300Б, 200Б
    # Строка может прилететь и "200Б, 300Б". Нужно точное соответствие 
    for string in strings:
        if re.search(pattern=f"{pattern}", string=string):
            print(pattern, "---", string)
            return "Success"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: не может ``in`` вернуть "МАШИН", если проверяет "МАШИНА". ``in`` вообще возвращает True или False, а не строку

Comment: @Эникейщик да понятно, что он возвращает. Суть в том, что он берет не ту строку, МАШИН попадает в МАШИНА и берётся первая, а не вторая

Comment: в вопросе написано, что нужно искать "МАШИНА". Зачем же вы ищите "МАШИН"?

Comment: @Эникейщик похоже, я неправильно сформулировал. Если мы напишем if МАШИНА in МАШИНАН, то будет True, а нужно False, я это имел ввиду, сейчас исправлю

Comment: попробуйте ``pattern=f"\W(МАШИНА)\W"``

Comment: @Эникейщик не подходит. Если мы ищем ВОРОНА, а первая  и вторая строка соответственно равны (КОТ, ВОРОНАН) и  (КОТН, ВОРОНА), то все равно он возьмет первую строку, а не вторую

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Приведите прямо кусок текста из нескольких строк и объясните, что вы таки ищете и почему нужно выбрать зайца, а не ворону, если второе слово в этих строках абсолютно одинаковое, а вы ищете вхождение именно в него. И если что шаблон границы слова это `\b`, т.е. чёткое соответствие регекспами не важно в каком месте строки и есть ли пробелы это будет типа `'\bМАШИНА\b'`.

Comment: @CrazyElf смотрите. Я ищу точное соответствие слова, допустим, это "200A". Далее я циклом прохожу по строкам, допустим, это две строки последовательно: Строка1="300Б, 200АБ" и Строка2="300Б, 200А". По идее, он должен взять строку2, потому что точное совпадение там. Но он возьмет строку1, поскольку 200А попадает под 200АБ. Мне нужно точное совпадение, то есть строка 2. Пробую я через re.search, pattern="\b{name}\b" не подходит, он все равно ловит строку1. Нужна вторая

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос как и где вы ищете, чтобы можно было повторить. Потому что у меня мой вариант находит МАШИНА, а МАШИНАН не находит.

Comment: @Эникейщик ищу так: if re.search(pattern=f"\W{name}\W",
                                                          string=string)

Comment: Как выглядят string и name?

Comment: @Эникейщик в точности так, как я описал CrazyElf сверху. Все равно берет первую строку

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста пример кода, чтобы его можно было скопировать и запустить, а не додумывать что там и как.

Comment: Чушь какая-то, у вас скорее наоборот не должно ничего находить, потому что \ надо ещё и экранировать и писать \\ либо использовать `r`-строки. Приведите конкретный полноценный пример, который можно запустить и увидеть, что вы имеете в виду. Не знаете как сделать пример - приведите что можете, мы дооформим.

Comment: @CrazyElf дополнил

Comment: Вот поменяйте в примере `pattern=f"\\b{pattern}\\b"` либо `pattern=fr"\b{pattern}\b"` и будет искать как нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте такой шаблон:

```
pattern=fr"\b{pattern}\b"
```

Объяснение: `\b` - это шаблон для границы слова.
Но кроме того обратные слэши нужно либо экранировать ещё одним бэкслэшэм, либо использовать "сырые" r-строки.

Answer (score 1):

Все понятно. `f"\W(МАШИНА)\W"` у вас не работало, потому что у вас паттерн в конце строки, а `\W` конец строки не учитывает. Вот так должно работать:

```
pattern=f"(^|\W){pattern}(\W|$)"
```

Comment: Не проще ли границу слова поставить, т.е. \b

Comment: С \b у меня почему-то не работало ‍♂️

Comment: Экранировать может надо? )

Comment: @CrazyElf ну точно, ``rf"\b{pattern}\b"`` или ``f"\\b{pattern}\\b"`` работает. А почему тогда для \W экранирование не требуется?

Comment: Наверное \W не соответствует никакой спецсимвол потому что )